# Пайтон и массивы

Tags: python, python-3.x

qq всем программистам. В общем начал я изучать массивы и тут проблема.

Есть код:

```
i = [1, [2, 5, 6], 3]
l=int((input("Какой массив тебе хочешь чтоб я написал? ")))
print(i[l])
```

Как сделать, чтобы если в инпуте будет слово, а не число, то не выдавало ошибку?

Comment: Все, что вводится в `input()` всегда строка. И при чем тут вообще массивы не понятно.

Comment: Здесь принято использовать Ctrl-C - Ctrl-V. А также ясно писать свой вопрос.

Comment: а как тогда сделать чтобы не выдавало ошибку если слово будет в инпуте?

Comment: в первом случае

Comment: я сейчас вопрос переделаю

Comment: RottenRat огромное спасибо

Comment: во-первых, не массивы, а списки. во-вторых, причем тут списки и массивы, если вопрос не про них?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `input()` всегда возращает `str`, а не `int`, здесь нужно преобразовывать типы

Как решение проблемы предлагаю подобный код

```
def isInt(string):
    try:
        result = int(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

i = [1, [2, 5, 6], 3]
l= input("Какой массив тебе хочешь чтоб я написал? ")
if isInt(l):
    print(i[int(l)])
else:
    print("Введи число, а не слово")
```

Также **СНОВА** обращаю внимание, что `input()` возращает `str`, поэтому не забываем преобразовать его в качестве индекса в `int`